# 401 Authentication when calling API on our network

Tags: c#, python, .net

I have a Rest Web API on one of our servers. A user has been making a call to this from python for a **year** now with no issues via:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Today it stopped working and is returning a 401: Unauthorized. It works for this person when the url is placed in Chrome/IE on his machine.

When I try connecting via a test C# app by using the WebClient object I notice that it works if I set the UseDefaultCredentials to true on the WebClient object. If I leave off this setting I get the same 401 error.

**My question would be why would this work for so long and then stop working and what would be the equivalent of this UseDefaultCredentials in the python call?**

Comment: has anything changed on the server or an update to the client software, must be something like this, things don't tend to suddenly stop without something happening first.

Comment: Check what authentication is being passed to the API when using Chrome, if you're on a local network, you may be using Windows domain auth for example which the browser will automatically set up for you.

Comment: OK, so what I just found out is that it used to allow anonymous and now it doesn't. It does this to get the AD id for the app. So need a way from python to send this information. However, I need some use default way because the app the user is trying to call IS a get password app so that passwords aren't hardcoded. So I can't hardcode a password in the call itself to get the password as that doesn't make sense.